# How to delete laravel delete file after extract?

Tags: php, laravel, zip

I am using [Zipper](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper) to extract uploaded zip file and delete the file after extract.
So I upload and extract like this:

```
$f = $request['file']->move(public_path($directory), $fullFileName);
\Zipper::make($f)->extractTo(public_path($directory) . $fileName);
```

and it works great. I've tried to delete the file using these ways.

```
1 - Storage::disk('products')->delete($fullFileName);
2 - File::delete(public_path($directory) . $fullFileName);
3 - $del = unlink(public_path($directory) . $fullFileName);
```

but in all actions get ***resource temporarily unavailable*** error.
I found this error is because of the zipper (simple files and directories works).

so my question is, **How can I delete upload zip file after extract, using a zipper?**

Any idea would be great. 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `$zipper->close();` after you extract it, so if you do something like this it should work:

```
$zipper = new \Chumper\Zipper\Zipper;
$zipper->make($f)->extractTo(public_path($directory) . $fileName);
$zipper->close();
unlink(public_path($directory) . $fullFileName);
```

If you do not close the zipper it will not write the result to the disk and keep the original file locked. See the [documentation](https://github.com/Chumper/Zipper).

Answer (score 2):

```
$zip = new Zipper;
$zip->make($pathZipFile)->extractTo($destinationPath);
$zip->close(); // important
unlink($pathZipFile); // delete Zip file after
```